# Pushbutton variable change not working

Tags: variables, button, arduino

I am a few days into programming with Arduino and I've run into an annoying problem. My circuit contains three LEDs connected to pins 2,3,4 and a push button connected to pin 8. What I want to do is alternate the lit LED by pressing the button. I'm using a variable to count which LED is lit at a certain point and resets when it reaches the value 4. The hardware part works fine, because I've tested it separately (automated alternation of the LEDs and the button example program in the Arduino IDE), so there has to be something with my code. What is it exactly?

```
void setup(){
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);

}

void loop(){
  int buton= digitalRead(8);
  int led = 1;

  if(led == 1){
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  }
  if(led == 2){
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  }
  if(led == 3){
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  }  
  if(buton == HIGH){
    led++;
    if(led == 4) led = 1;
  }

}
```

I know for a fact that it doesn't enter the last if (the one for the button input value) because I've placed a Serial.println() to see both the value of variable led and a constant string and it didn't show.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should try moving `int led = 1;` into your setup function, otherwise it will reset to `1` every time your loop runs.

Comment: That was the first thought, but if I move it there it gives the error that i wasn't declared "in this scope". They are different functions with different local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smilledge was right in the comments, the led variable was reset to 1 at every iteration of the loop. I wasn't aware you could have variable declarations outside the two functions (setup and loop), so I just made the variable global.